# Testing if data normally distributed and interpretation!

Tags: normal-distribution, p-value, skewness, kurtosis

I have two question related to if data are normal distributed or not and interpretation.  I am using R for my analysis

**About my Data:**

- I have a data set X (lets assume they are females) that consist of G groups (Grouped based on where they live).
- I am applying two approaches (A1, A2) to find the tallest female in each group.
- What I am comparing is: The time each approach takes to find the tallest female in each group.

**About Statistics:**

Function I am using in R (Studio) to calculate Wilcox is: wilcox.test(A1, A2, correct = F)

**Question (1):** Is this the right way to use the test for my data?

Kurtosis and Skewness are used to see if the data are normally distributed. If both of them greater or less than 0 then it means that the data are not normally distributed.

When Kurtosis and Skewness not 0 & Wilcoxon (p-value) > 0.05 means: Not normally distributed and distribution is different.

But what about when:

**Question (2):** When Kurtosis and Skewness not 0 and 0 < Wilcoxon (p-value) < 0.05?

Edited:
The reason I am doing this is, I want to compare the two approaches A1 and A2 in term of which one is faster. The problem I don't know which one to use the Mean or the Median, as if:

- The data are not normally distributed then I should use the median.
- The data are normally distributed then I should use the mean (average).

so I am applying these three tests to decide which one to use.

Comment: The Wilcoxon rank-sum test is non-parametric, meaning (among other things) that normality in your data is not important with regard to the test. Is there a specific reason that you want to examine normality here?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Questions that are solely about programming or carrying out an operation within a statistical package are [off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site and may be closed.  However, it appears that you do have an underlying statistical question.  Please edit to de-emphasize the use of R and R functions and outline more generally the statistical concepts you are asking about

Comment: I don't know R functions called *kurtosis* or *skewness*, so I can't comment on those. Your call to wilcox.test will execute successfully, but whether or not those are the correct arguments to use depends on exactly what you want to find. The documentation for wilcox.test has more information on those arguments. Your interpretation of the p-value of the rank sum test seems backward to me. Unless I've misunderstood what you wrote, a p-value less than your alpha (0.05) should support the idea that the two samples were drawn from populations with different height distributions.

Comment: Times taken to do something are inevitably positive and usually right skewed. A deeper analysis would start with a more realistic null model, such as an exponential distribution. Even if you measure or test skewness or kurtosis you won't establish thereby a good framework for analysis.

Comment: What are A1 and A2?  What is RStudio doing?  How does Wilcoxon and normality testing come into ?  Perhaps if we know A1 and A2 we can better see how the groups are picked to look for the tallest woman and how time becomes a factor.  If you are looking for the tallest why is your question involving medians?  I understand that if you have normality the mean would best estimate the center of the distribution and for other shaped distributions it could be the median.  Do you see all the gaps in your explanation?

Comment: The mean may be a perfectly sensible measure to use when distributions are skewed. (To take Nick Cox's example, of a case using an exponential model for times, then it makes complete sense not only to talk about the population mean of times, but to use the sample mean to estimate it) ... you seem to have accumulated a number of not really correct notions that are leading you to do things that may not be helpful or to avoid doing what could be quite sensible things to do. It may be better to focus on the underlying problem rather than asking about your attempts at a solution to that problem.

Comment: We have a ton of comments and the OP hasn't responded to any of them.. One might help give us some indication of the gaps in logic and most importantly whether the objective is to find the maximum heights quickly or something else.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, I believe all the info I can give is there. A1 and A2 as I mentioned are two approaches (Algorithms, my thesis so can't tell more). Also if you read the last part I am stating what I am trying to do :"I want to compare the two approaches A1 and A2 in term of which one is faster". Also Median and Means returns single value, so the returned value for A1 and A2 I will use to compare. I hope this is what you are asking for!